# Assume in lean 4

Tags: lean

A lot of proofs in Lean 3 were structured via the `assume` syntax e.g.

```
theorem WetTheorem : 
forall Rain Hydrant Wet: Prop, 
    (Rain ∨ Hydrant) → -- raining or hydrant on;
    (Rain → Wet) →     -- if raining then wet;
    (Hydrant → Wet) →  -- if hydrant on then wet;
    Wet                -- then wet
:=
begin
-- setup
  assume Rain Hydrant Wet,
  assume RainingOrHydrantRunning: (Rain ∨ Hydrant),
  assume RainMakesWet: (Rain → Wet),
  assume HydrantMakesWet: (Hydrant → Wet),
-- the core of the proof
  cases RainingOrHydrantRunning with raining running,
    show Wet, from RainMakesWet raining,
    show Wet, from HydrantMakesWet running,
end
```

I was unable find a similar reference section for tactics in lean 4 like in [3](https://leanprover.github.io/reference/tactics.html#structured-tactic-proofs), and it seems `assume` has been dropped. What would be the general method of converting a lean 3 proof with `assume` into a lean 4 without it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assume` in tactic mode can be replaced by `intro` with a type ascription in lean 4, so your entire code can be written as follows

```
theorem WetTheorem : 
forall Rain Hydrant Wet: Prop, 
    (Rain ∨ Hydrant) → -- raining or hydrant on;
    (Rain → Wet) →     -- if raining then wet;
    (Hydrant → Wet) →  -- if hydrant on then wet;
    Wet                -- then wet
:=
by
-- setup
  intro Rain Hydrant Wet
  intro (RainingOrHydrantRunning : (Rain ∨ Hydrant))
  intro (RainMakesWet: (Rain → Wet))
  intro (HydrantMakesWet: (Hydrant → Wet))
-- the core of the proof
  cases RainingOrHydrantRunning
  case inl raining =>
    exact RainMakesWet raining
  case inr running =>
    exact HydrantMakesWet running
```